# Ubuntu 20.04 Open a Port

Tags: networking, firewall

I use Nordvpn.   I whitelisted port 8000 so that I access ajenti control panel, however nmap still shows that the internal / external IP addresses have port 8000 blocked.

```
External IP Output
$ nmap -sT 88.88.88.88 --reason -p 8000
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-02 08:34 CST
Nmap scan report for unn-88-88-88-88.cdn77.com (88.88.88.88)
Host is up, received conn-refused (0.041s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE  REASON
8000/tcp filtered http-alt no-response

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.74 seconds

Internal IP Output
$ nmap -sT 100.100.100.100 --reason -p 8000
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-02 08:34 CST
Nmap scan report for timbuktu (100.100.100.100)
Host is up, received syn-ack (0.000071s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE  REASON
8000/tcp closed http-alt conn-refused

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
```

I completely turned of nordvpn's firewall and killswitch, but nmap still shows the port as filtered.

```
nmap -sT rawip# --reason -p 8000
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-02 14:26 CST
Nmap scan report for 888.88.888.88
Host is up, received syn-ack (0.0016s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE  REASON
8000/tcp filtered http-alt no-response

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.25 seconds
```

**Additional info:**
Yes, I forwarded the port 8000 on the router to my internal IP as well

Current Nordvpn Settings:

```
$ nordvpn settings
Technology: NordLynx
Firewall: enabled
Kill Switch: enabled
CyberSec: disabled
Notify: enabled
Auto-connect: enabled
DNS: disabled
Whitelisted ports:
         8000 (UDP|TCP)
Whitelisted subnets:
    887.888.888.888/24
```

Problem also existed with these settings:

```
$ nordvpn settings
Technology: OpenVPN
Protocol: UDP
Firewall: enabled
Kill Switch: disabled
CyberSec: disabled
Obfuscate: disabled
Notify: enabled
Auto-connect: disabled
DNS: disabled
Whitelisted ports:
         8000 (UDP|TCP)
Whitelisted subnets:
    888.888.8.8/24
```

Also, as previously mentioned, I completely disabled the firewall and killswitch  and forwarded the port on the router, but the problem persists.

FYI, I completely reset Nordvpn settings using the commands below and the problem still persists:

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/nordvpn/data/settings.dat
[sudo] password for username:
username@moachine:~$ sudo rm -rf ~/.config/nordvpn
```

How do I open port 8000?

(UFW is also inactive)

Comment: Have you opened it on your router?

Comment: After, I saw your comment, I opened the port on the router... still shows blocked by nmap :-/

Comment: I don't know what you mean by open the port in router. You have to forward the port 8000 in the router to your internal IP address.

Comment: I corrected my terminology in the post.  But, yes I forwarded the port to my internal ip in the router.

Comment: Also using VPN. I using it via terminal commands.

Try use nordVPN via chrome/ff existension. For some reason, I got the same issue when using the terminal and as browser extensions. If you use nov via a terminal to connect. Also, add a port in a firewall? can you post $nordvpn settings

Comment: @dMatija I updated the post to show settings that I tried.

Comment: If you didn't, I suggest you turn off nordvpn and then try what you try to do. If it works, then move to with nordvpn. Disable all and go step by step. Also, try to use nordvpn just as browser extensions. 

Some text on the nordvpn website says they close all ports, like 99%, when VPN is active. Not sure how I solve the problem since it was a bit of a long time ago.

Comment: @dMatija I tried it with Nordvpn completely deactivated, and was not successful in opening port 8000. That is why I started this post.   I will try with the browser extension next.